# The proper use of measurement units?

Tags: html, css, units-of-measurement

I've been using `px` for almost all the measurement related styling, but I wanted to know the best places for the use of pixels (`px`), percentage (`%`), points (`pt`) and `em`.
I've seen the use of `em` and (I believe) `points` in typography, but I don't know the best way to use them.

Where should either be used, and why?

Comment: Good question.  The type of question that launches 10,000 blog posts.

Comment: Good article at http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: just edited my answer and added this link (before seeing your comment)... great indeed.

Comment: Oh and there really is no one, "best way". Depending on your needs, different units will work best. A question like this is open to opinion and debate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `pt` or `cm`, `in`, `mm` etc. are most used for print stylesheets, as they're most fit for measurements on the physical properties of paper sheets, and the render of printers.
- `em` and `en` ([and the new `rem`](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem), and more interesting units such as `ch`) are glyph relative units, and as such are suitable for text styling, in correspondence with absolute units at the root element (e.g. `px` units at the `body`). 
  *another interesting uses: `ex` units (the height of the 'x' glyph in the font) to set vertical measures in relation to text, `ch` to indent lines.*
- `px` are absolutely rendered so one can design a pixel-perfect (or fixed) layout based on these units, applied for containers, or on various widgets demanding fixed size (buttons and the like). *disclaimer: absolutely is an over-statement, as pixels are rarely absolute, and has many factors affecting the rendered outcome - see [this article about px as an angular measure](http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx).*
- `%` are mostly used in conjunction with an absolute unit at the top container, and are applied in various CSS techniques, such as the faux centered container. these units are also very handy for layouts that are fluid by nature. *others, like the viewport relative `vh`, `vw` and `vmin`, may be used regardless of the parent's units*.

*all of the above is based on my personal views, as this subject is open for debate, and CSS techniques will keep evolve and we'll see more uses of the specifications and capabilities we had never thought of. it's mostly the creative use of those tools that scopes or favors the use of one unit over another.*

Comment: `px` actually has little relation to on-screen pixels, due to e.g. zooming, high DPI displays, mobile devices, etc. It's instead defined as an angular unit: http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx

Comment: thanks, i've updated my answer accordingly, as this is an important issue to be aware of.

Comment: I had no idea about these new units! Thank you very much for your information :)

Answer (score 4):

It used to be that these distinctions mattered: for example, back in the IE6 days, you should never set your text using `px`, because then it couldn't be zoomed. That is, back in the day, browsers actually treated `px` as a number of pixels.

These days, browsers have conformed to web reality: most people use `px` everywhere, for almost everything. Thus [`px` is now defined as an angular measurement](http://inamidst.com/stuff/notes/csspx), which essentially means that `px` behaves just fine in any zoom setting and on any size or DPI device.

Similarly, as part of conforming to web reality, all other units are defined in terms of `px`, so there is really no reason to use them unless it happens to be more convenient for your case. The only exception is, of course, percentages, since they allow you to specify values in relation to parents' measurements.

Details [from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units):

- **`in`, `cm`, `mm`, `pt`, and `pc` are all defined relative to `px`**, since in practice all devices follow *"For a CSS device, these dimensions are ... anchored ... (ii) by relating the pixel unit to the reference pixel."* And as discussed, the "reference pixel" is an angular measurement that varies depending on DPI settings, screen size, zoom level, device type and so on.
- **`1em` equals the computed `font-size` of an element**, which is usually defined in `px`. If that size itself is defined in `em`s or `ex`s, the browser then looks upward until it finds a `px` to be relative to, eventually falling back to the default `font-size` (usually `12px`).
- **`1ex` equals the height of the letter "x" in the defined `font-size`** if possible, but usually (?) falls back to `0.5em`.

Comment: So, would it be fine if I use ``em`` only for typography?

Comment: Sure. Just be aware you're really looking at `px` underneath it all; something like `1em = 12px`.

Answer (score 1):

Use px for elements that are  of a set size.
Use percentage when you need the element to be in proportion to the window size or parent element size.

em is the standard for text, it adjust according to screen size on a mac. Make it a habit, there's plenty of good blogs on why to use em, em is not just for font properties it also comes in handy with other elements like div, inputs etc. There may be consequences when using px for font size, there's also situations where px and % will be more ideal, it' takes trial & error to understand fully.

There are no real rule on what to use it's all according to the desired effect. As you create you will test your site in different resolutions and adjust the browser size to see how it appears from a variety of users points of view.

Consider cross browser compatibility & resolution with em, 
Consider resolution with percentages,

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I am a sysadmin, not a web designer.

I generally use `em` for padding around images, so as to keep the padding sized according to the text it keeps away from the image.

I use `%` to handle liquid/fluid layouts sometimes, though most often a fluid layout will just be 100% of the browser but with fixed width (`px`) columns.

I use `px` to handle column widths, headers, etc.  The `height` and `width` attributes of an `<img>` tag are of course in pixels by default, and an image will render best if you don't ask the browser to resize it from its native/original resolution.  In some cases, you need to use `px` on fonts, when the font has to work with an image (i.e. a spanner icon next to the word "Tools").  If possible, I always use UTF-8 fonts instead of images.